# Call mysql PROCEDURE inside while loop works only first time

Tags: php, mysql, loops, stored-procedures, procedure

I have some data from the DB I post on a table. For every line of the table (every loop of the while loop), I need to CALL a stored procedure to calculate the data for the last `<td>` of my table.

Here some code:

```
$s = $lk->query("SELECT *
                  FROM A_USERS
                  JOIN A_DATA
                  WHERE A_DATA.id_user = A_USERS.id
                    AND A_USERS.usr_att = 1
                    AND A_DATA.act_data = 1
                    AND A_DATA.a_att = 1
                    AND A_DATA.qty IS NOT NULL
                  ORDER BY ID ASC");


while ($dato = $s->fetch_object()) {
    print '<tr>';

    print '<td>';   
    print $dato->id;
    print '</td>';

    //others cells


    $GetP = $lk->query("CALL GetPr($dato->qty, '$dato->prod')");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($GetP) === 1){
        while($p_db = mysqli_fetch_array($GetP)){
            $p = $p_db['p'];
        }

        $format = number_format(round($p, 1), 2, ',', '\'');

        //some other stuff here...

    }else{
        print '<td>';
        print 'ERROR';
        print '</td>';
    }
    print '</tr>';
}
```

The problem is that ONLY the first loop of the `while` calls the procedure which returns `1 row`. Else I get always `ERROR` on this `<td>` which means the stored procedure didn't return `1 row`.

Why?

**EDIT**

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`...` PROCEDURE `GetPr`(IN `cli_qty` INT, IN `cli_prod` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET ascii)
BEGIN
    SET @cli_qty = cli_qty;

    SET @q = (SELECT qty FROM MRG_H ORDER BY ABS(@cli_qty - qty) ASC LIMIT 1);

    SET @cli_prod = cli_prod;

    IF @cli_prod = 'OECO' THEN SET @marg = (SELECT (m+v) FROM MRG_H JOIN DT WHERE m <> '' AND q = @q AND par = 'MarOECO');

    ELSE SET @marg = (SELECT m FROM MRG_H WHERE m <> '' AND q = @q);
    END IF;

    SELECT (Med+@marg)*((Val+100)/100) AS P, D_aaaammgg AS Date
        FROM PL
          JOIN TVA
        WHERE I_D = 0
      AND Med <> ''
      AND Date_f = ''
        ORDER BY Iden DESC
        LIMIT 1;
END
```

MYSQLI ERROR:

```
Error: 2014-Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Comment: The procedure works fine. If I call it from `PHP My Admin` with the data of every rows, it works! Anyway I post it now

Comment: Maybe it doesn't return 1 row for any of the other rows in your first query. Did you verify that? Also, invalid data could be a problem. `$dato->qty` could be `null` or `$dato->prod` could contain a `'` or be `null`. In cases like that, the call to the procedure becomes invalid.

Comment: The Procedure returns error (if I add `or die(...)` after the `CALL Procedure` it dies. The `$dato->qty` is an integer and can't be `NULL` and `$dato->prod` has only two possibilities `HEL` and `OECO`

Comment: Could you provide some more details about the *error*. Does [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) returns something?

Comment: Error: 2014-Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With suggestions of @Mihai I found this solution:

Reference: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904)

```
while ($dato = $s->fetch_object()) {
    print '<tr>';

    print '<td>';   
    print $dato->id;
    print '</td>';

    //others cells


    $GetP = $lk->query("CALL GetPr($dato->qty, '$dato->prod')");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($GetP) === 1){
        while($p_db = mysqli_fetch_array($GetP)){
            $p = $p_db['p'];
        }

        $format = number_format(round($p, 1), 2, ',', '\'');

        //some other stuff here...

    }else{
        print '<td>';
        print 'ERROR';
        print '</td>';
    }

    //Added this 2 lines
    $GetPrice->close();
    $link->next_result();

    print '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No sure this is the problem,but mysqli_fetch_array advances the internal pointer,replace it with mysqli_num_rows instead.

```
while($p_db = mysqli_fetch_array($GetP)){
        $p = $p_db['p'];
    }
```

EDIT:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904

```
$s->close();

$lk->next_result();
```

Put this 2 under //other cells.

And also,ty replacing fetch_object with fetch_all.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::close() in /.../test.php on line 130`
This is code now:
`print '</td>';
$dato->close();
$s->next_result();
$GetP = $lk->query("CALL GetPr($dato->qty, '$dato->prod')");
`

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_object() [mysqli-result.fetch-object]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in /.../test.php on line 94`. This is line 94:
`while ($dato = $s->fetch_object()) {`
This is normal, cause we close the data

Comment: Ok solution founded! I post an answer